# calc expression in SASS

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, github-pages

In an SCSS file, I have this line of code:

```scss
@return calc((#{$span-width} / #{$container}) * 100%);
```

And it produces this error:

```
Undefined operation "-1 * calc((3 / 14.75) * 100%)".
```

I don't understand where the `-1` is coming from. What's more, the error only occurs when the site is being generated on GitHub but not on my machine. I have been
[struggling to](https://github.com/pwintz/pwintz.github.io/actions/runs/4412573395/jobs/7732156323)
[remove the error](https://github.com/pwintz/pwintz.github.io/actions/runs/4423678760/jobs/7756652771)
[for a while.](https://github.com/pwintz/pwintz.github.io/actions/runs/4423805467/jobs/7756901345)

Some other versions that I have tried are:

```scss
@return percentage(math.div($span-width, $container));
```

```scss
@return math.div($span-width, $container) * 100%;
```

```scss
@return calc(($span-width / $container) * 100%);
```

```scss
@return calc(math.div($span-width, $container) * 100%)
```

I'm brand new to SASS and am only using `.scss` files that were included in a Jekyll theme, so I don't know how to provide an MWE in this case. Any help would be appreciated!

The full function:

```scss
@function su-span(
  $span,
  $columns,
  $gutters,
  $spread,
  $container-spread: $spread,
  $location: 1
) {
  $span: su-valid-span($span);
  $columns: su-valid-columns($columns);
  $gutters: su-valid-gutters($gutters);
  $spread: su-valid-spread($spread);

  @if (type-of($span) == 'number') {
    @if (not unitless($span)) {
      @return $span;
    }

    $location: su-valid-location($span, $location, $columns);
    $span: su-slice($span, $columns, $location, $validate: false);
  }

  @if _su-needs-calc-output($span, $columns, $gutters, $spread, not 'validate') {
    @return _su-calc-span($span, $columns, $gutters, $spread, $container-spread, not 'validate');
  }

  $span-width: _su-sum($span, $gutters, $spread, $validate: false);

  @if unitless($span-width) {
    $container-spread: su-valid-spread($container-spread);
    $container: _su-sum($columns, $gutters, $container-spread, $validate: false);
    @return #{calc((#{$span-width} / #{$container}) * 100%)};
  }

  @return $span-width;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ultimately solved my problem was by changing the repository settings from "deploy from branch" to "GitHub Actions".

Comment: Do you know what are the differences between the two types of deployments? What each does/doesn't do?

Comment: No, I don't. My guess is that there is a version difference somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's caused by this nested interpolation:

```scss
@return #{calc((#{$span-width} / #{$container}) * 100%)};
```

Remove the outer one:

```scss
@return calc((#{$span-width} / #{$container}) * 100%);
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```scss
@return #{calc(($span-width / $container) * 100%)};
```

To be fair, I don't understand why you're using interpolation here in the first place. This should work:

```scss
@return calc(($span-width / $container) * 100%);
```

I can't test it without knowing what each of the functions used are doing and what values you're using.
Consider creating a *runnable* [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/), if you need more help.

Comment: Using `@return calc((#{$span-width} / #{$container}) * 100%);` produces the following error: `Undefined operation "-1 * calc((3 / 14.75) * 100%)".`

Comment: Using `@return #{calc(($span-width / $container) * 100%)};` produces this error: `Undefined operation "-1 * 20.3389830508%"`.

Comment: Hmm... I just changed the way I'm building the page on GitHub and it seems to be working. I'll test it a bit more and then give you the bounty if it really is resolved.